# How could I set a mark with keybinding `Ctrl+space` on Sublime Text`?

Tags: sublimetext, key-bindings

On `emacs` by default `Ctrl+space` sets a mark and later when I press up/down arrow the selection expands.

I am using `emacs` keybindings on `Sublime Text` via [Emacs Pro Essentials](https://github.com/sublime-emacs/sublemacspro).
But on `Sublime Text`, I need to do `Ctrl+space+space` in order to set a mark. First `space` puts a dot next the line and the seconds space actually selects it.

**[Q]** How could I set a mark with keybinding `Ctrl+space` on Sublime Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this by adding `"sbp_active_mark_mode": true` to your Emacs Pro Essentials settings file.

```
{
  "sbp_active_mark_mode": true,

  [some-setting]: [value],

  [another-setting]: [value]
}
```

The file's default Windows location is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\<profile name>\sublemacpro.sublime-settings`.
You can also find it through the menu bar: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emacs Pro Essentials -> Settings - <profile name>`.

The region between the point and mark is only selected if the mark is active, and this setting causes newly created marks to be active by default.